# Lebesgue integral question using du Boise-Reymond lemma

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, calculus-of-variations

This question was inspired a previous question of mine. If we are given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open and bounded and $$\int_{\Omega}fv dx = 0$$ where $f \in C(\Omega)$ and $v \in C^{\infty}_{o}(\Omega)$. Then by du Boise-Reymond lemma we have that $f = 0$ a.e. Can anyone show that we can further show that $f = 0$ everywhere? This is a link to the definition of [du Boise-Reymond lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).

Thanks.

Comment: $f$ is continuous. So the set where $f(x) \neq 0$ is open. An open set with Lebesgue measure $0$ is ...

Comment: @DanielFischer...is the emptyset. How do you show that if $f$ is continuous then $f(x) \neq 0$ is open?

Comment: It's the preimage of an open set, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes, of course. So a continuous function can never be equal to a constant almost everywhere?

Comment: You mean "without being constant", I suppose. Yes, for the Lebesgue measure and similar measures (such that every nonempty open set has positive measure). If the measure is different (point mass, for example), you can't conclude "almost everywhere implies everywhere for continuous functions" of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes agreed. I haven't worked with any other measures, but I will look at a few now. Would you also have used du Boise-Reymond lemma to show that $f = 0$ a.e.?

Answer (score 0):

If a continuous function $f$ satisfies $f=0$ on a dense subset of $\Omega$, then $f=0$ everywhere in $\Omega$. This follows from any definition of continuity you may be using: with limits or open sets. A set whose complement has zero measure is   dense.

Comment: Okay I see, for the limit argument, I can say take any x in the set of measure zero, then since we have a dense subset there exists a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ in the dense subset such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. Since $f$ is continuous it follows that $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$, but $f(x_{n}) = 0 \text{ for all } n$, therefore $f(x) = 0$. Do you have a good reference for the proof of why the complement of a dense set has measure zero, or a hint of how to prove it?

Comment: @JohnDoe You switched the order of implication. Proof by contrapositive: if the complement of a ser contains a ball, then it' has positive measure. Because the ball does.